# Find an object element in a List

Tags: c#

I have a data file filled with Dog{Name, Classification, Country, Use} lines. I made a **Class** explaining what dogs are and a **List** to store them.
Everything works without the checks I'm now adding.

I'd like to check if a Dog name already exists in the list, so I add this condition :

```
if(Dog.IndexOf(Fields[0]) == -1)
```

but I have the error

> Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'string' in Dogs.Program.Dogs

Here is the portion of code:

```
public class Dogs
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Classification { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Use { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Dogs> Dog = new List<Dogs>();

        try
        {
            bool Erreur = false;
            using (StreamReader File = new StreamReader("../../Data/dogs.txt", Encoding.UTF8, true))
            {
                while (!Fichier.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string Line = File.ReadLine();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Line))
                    {
                        string[] Fields = Line.Split('\t');

                        if (Fields.Length == 4)
                        {
                            if(Dogs.IndexOf(Fields[0]) == -1)
                            {
                                Dogs AddDog = new Dogs();
                                AddDog.Name = Fields[0];
                                AddDog.Classification = Fields[1];
                                AddDog.Country = Fields[2];
                                AddDog.Use = Fields[3];
                                Chien.Add(AddDog);
                            }
...
```

How can I check the 'Name' attribute of objects stroed in this list ?

Comment: Your code has some naming errors and that makes it kind of hard to read. For example, the name of your class is `Dogs` and the name of your list is `Dog`.

Comment: Using `Find`, `Where` or `FirstOrDefault`  as suggested in the suggested duplicate doesn't make much sense when you just want to determine whether the list contains a particular element. If you're going to close a question as a duplicate, then please pick one with an appropriate answer.

Comment: Unfortunately you designated your question as finding duplicates in a list and therefore it was closed having answers already.  Hint: Linq, and your real problem is using a txt file as if it were a database. ie: 
           var  dogs = File.ReadAllLines("../../Data/dogs.txt", Encoding.UTF8)
      .Select (f => f.Split('\t'))
      .Where( f => f.Length == 4)
      .Select (f => new Dog {
          Name=f[0], 
          Classification=f[1],
          Country=f[2],
          Use=f[3]
            });

Comment: The answer of @mm8 with LINQ did the trick, thx to him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to determine whether there is a `Dogs` object with a `Name` that equals `Fields[0]` in the `Dog` list:

```
if (!Dog.Any(x => x.Name == Fields[0]))
{
    Dogs AddDog = new Dogs();
    ...
```

Comment: I disagree with the downvoter, you were directing towards a better solution.